# grep a range of characters (decimal encoding)

Tags: grep, regular-expression, ascii

I have a list of accepted characters:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHI
```

These characters can be translated in the [ASCII decimal range](http://defindit.com/ascii.html) 33-73

The implementation I'd like would parse the lines of an input file, detecting any character out of this range, and returning the corresponding line.

```
grep -E '[^33-73]{1,}'
```

where `-E` is for regex interpretation, `^` is for matching any characters NOT in the list, `{1,}`is for matching one or more occurrences... and `[33-73]` is a way to symbolize the wanted range of characters in decimal format, I don't know how to express this in a way it's interpretable by `grep`.

(I could define the list of characters in the regex itself, but escaping of reserved `grep -E` characters makes the expression hard to read.)

Is there a way to implement this in `grep`?
(FYI trying to make it work on `(BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`)

Example input:

```
$ cat f1.txt
(ABC123abc_
ABC!123)-
```

Expected output:

```
(ABC123abc_
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since these are consecutive characters in ASCII, you should be able to simply do:

```
$ grep '[^!-I]' file
(ABC123abc_
```

Or, safer in case you have a different locale:

```
$ LC_ALL=C grep '[^!-I]' file
(ABC123abc_
```